# How to make a list based on two other lists in java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to make a new list which is based on the values ​​of two lists and has as many elements as the first list, e.g.

Input:

```
MyOjbect: int key1, int key2;

List1<Integer>: {1,2,3,3,2}



List2<MyObject>: {{20,5},
         {21,4},
         {22,3},
         {23,2},
         {24,1},
         {25,0},
         {26,-1}}
```

Output(a list with the same number of elements as the first list):

```
List3<Integer>: {24,23,22,22,23}
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this?

Comment: take successive elements from the first list, search for the same element (key2) in the second list, and save key1 of this found element to the result list

Comment: That explanation is needed in the actual question

Comment: @LinFelix List two contains objects based on K/V. List one contains V from these objects. The user wants the keys depends on elements in list one. Your are right, the post is in poor quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible approaches to this. The following basic solution has a quadratic time complexity, so it's not good if List2 is large:

```java
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Integer key : List1) {
   for (MyObject obj : List2) {
      if (obj.getSecondElement().equals(key)) {
         result.add(obj.getFirstElement());
      }
   }
}
```

If the List2 is large than you better construct a map from it's second element to the first one first, and then make search in this map.